# Angularjs format date

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

Printing a date like:

```
{{current.sys.sunrise | date:date}}
```

Problem is it is being stored in the database as for example: 1476873429.
Believe it is milliseconds from 1970.
The output is something like: Jan 18, 1970.

Is some kind of custom filter required to format it to current time?

Answer (score 2):

You should multiply your timestamps by 1000, you're storing seconds but JavaScript `Date`s take milliseconds as arguments :

```
console.log(new Date(1476873429)) // outputs Sun Jan 18 1970
console.log(new Date(1476873429 * 1000)) // outputs Wed Oct 19 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

i.e

```
 <span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span>:
    <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>:
   <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span>:
   <span>{{'1288323623006' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span>:
   <span>{{'1288323623006' | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span><br>
```

Comment: any idea on how to get the date to $filter when it is in $scope.current.sys.sunrise?